# Android TV App to login activate using website with any device with code

Tags: android, flutter, android-tv

I'm developing a simple app for Android TV using Flutter.

I would like to add authenticated users.

Android TV would display something like:

To login go to [www.domain.com/activate](http://www.domain.com/activate) on any device and enter this code: ABC123XYZ

Once logged in on a phone or computer and the code is entered Android TV app is authenticated and ready for future use.

Just wondering how is this implemented, any help is appreciated.

Comment: As I understood, I think that you need a server to authenticate users. The normal case is to have a back-end side responsible for this task, in this case, you just send credentials through an API from your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple-way you can perform this

1. Websocket
2. API services

First let's check for API Web Services, create a page for Android TV users and send the code they have entered from remote to the server let the user do the computation and get back that user is authenticated.
Although I personally do not like this feature as typing on tv is rather a bad user experience with the remote keypad.

Let's go with the WebSocket, create a QR code with UUID information on tv, connect tv app with WebSocket to receive authentication updates, then scan QR code via a mobile app the code that you have generated on tv is UUID of that tv and you got unique token after scanning, now send this UUID to the server and server will fire socket message to the TV that you have been authenticated.

also, it would be best if you go to your backend developer regarding this query is regarding flow and that can be determined by any backend engineer.

Comment: WebSockets are best to reduce the number of keyboard inputs from the user, I will suggest that but you can go with both use cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! i'm thinking more simpler than websockets.
Do you think this could work:
- androidtvapp starts if no auth in shared_preferences displays activation widget which fetches a random code from php api backend this code also saved on php backend to codes table...
- android tv app keeps requesting now with its activation code every few seconds...
- when user logs in on the php website and enters this code backend will also respond with authenticated response, save activation code to users table etc.
- android tv app saves to shared_preferences, loads main widget.

Comment: yes, even if you don't want to call API too frequent it's fine. put a button to login and prompt if not authorized that you need to login via app here's the code kind of..
after all, the user can click a login button for sure.

Comment: also close this question as it's regarding flow and other than what I have suggested there isn't any option to log in.

Comment: @ParthDave I have a similar login flow in my app. I made a demo account (to be used in the browser) and shared these credentials along with instruction on `App Content > App Access > All or some functinoality is restricted`. But, Google keeps rejecting stating provide Login Info. But, no other information is being shared on multiple requests. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest implementing

https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/device-code/

Your app would periodically poll the server asking if authenticated

once the user has gone to said website and put in said code, the next poll you would return a token etc. for the app to use and then let your app do its thing.